# Is there any difference in "if" vs. "takeIf" in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Which of the following two implementations is better:

1.use "if"

```
fun f1(a: A?): R? {
    if (a != null) {
        val b = getB(a)
        if (b != null && b.f()) {
            val c = getC(b)
            if (c != null && c.f()) {
                return c.f2()
            }
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

2.use "takeIf" and "let"

```
fun f2(a: A?): R? = a
        ?.let { getB(it) }
        ?.takeIf { it.f() }
        ?.let { getC(it) }
        ?.takeIf { it.f() }
        ?.let { it.f2() }
```

Comment: Kindly share the scenario based on which you want to compare.

Comment: Please don't put so much code in the comments. It's very hard to read. Edit your question instead.

Comment: @Thomas  see question.

Comment: Which one would you rather read?

Answer (score 3):

"takeIf" and "let" is the better approach. Though it is bit harder at first but as you will be experienced with lambda expression you will find them really help full.

Kotlin is the new language and one of the advantage is to remove boilerplate code.

```
fun f2(a: A?): R? = a
        ?.let { getB(it) }
        ?.takeIf { it.f() }
        ?.let { getC(it) }
        ?.takeIf { it.f() }
        ?.let { it.f2() }
```

This code snippet does exactly that. It just removed ugly 4 level nesting of if conditions.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

This is kind of a subjective question. Some people like one version, others like another.
Personally, I think this is more readable:

```
fun f3(a: A?): R? {
    if (a == null) {
        return null
    }

    val b = getB(a)
    if (b == null || !b.f()) {
        return null
    }

    val c = getC(b)
    if (c == null || !c.f()) {
        return null
    }

    return c.f2()
}
```

Comment: That is just so very nice and clear!

Answer (score -1):

The let/takeIf in this example is very hard to read.  Perhaps different indentation would help, but the fact that the function names are so artificial and the result of each get has an identically named 'f' function all contributes to the problem.

Let and takeIf can be highly readable in more normal cases.

Breaking into separate statements in this artificial case whether using let/takeIf or conventional 'if' helps with this example.

Comment: This is just an example. I can't put the complete code, it can't be submitted. In the case of normal naming, let/takeIf is better?

Comment: if you mean better than 'if'.... then sometimes yes, sometimes no.  I suggest best to evaluate on a case by case base use both 'if' and 'let/takeIf' depending on which reads better in each use case